# Stripe: customers cannot pay an invoice with credit card

Tags: stripe-payments

When I send an Invoice to a Customer by email, customer is able open an Invoice, but it's not possible to pay with credit card, so, this invoice seems like useless at all, because there is no option to pay it.

Some our customers can connect bank account, but by default all customers have to be able to pay with credit card.

We don't need to store customers' cards on our side, just allow to use cards.

What is easiest way to allow using credit cards for a customer? I see different options in Stripe doc:

1. Create PaymentMethod, then set invoice_settings.default_payment_method for a Customer
2. Create Sources, then set it to Customer.default_source.

But I'm not sure if it's possible to create payment method or source without card details.

There is a chance that our Stripe account is configured incorrectly, not sure what exactly I have to check.

Comment: Maybe you don't have Cards enabled as an option under "Default payment terms" at https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/invoice

Comment: I see that 2 payment methods are enabled: ACH and debit/credit cards.

Comment: @karllekko aha, you are right -- credit cards were disabled on connected stripe account (I didn't have access to it to check)